# Maven - System Jar provoded by Websphere Library

Tags: maven, dependencies, system, dependency-management

I have two questions regarding dependencies:

Q1: I have a **j2ee.jar** on my unix box (provided by Websphere Library). This is how I refer it in ANT:

```
<path id="was.lib">
 <fileset dir="${was.home}/lib">
  <include name="**/j2ee.jar" />
 </fileset>
</path>
<property name="was.lib" refid="was.lib" />
<path id="myProj.lib">
 <!-- path to my project's JAR's -->
</path>
<property name="myProj.lib" refid="myProj.lib" />
<path id="myProj.classpath">
 <path refid="myProj.lib" />
 <path refid="was.lib" />
</path>
```

I am not sure, how to define this dependency in Maven so that it refers to the system path?

Q2: I have a jar **castor-1.3.1.jar** and **castor-1.3.1-core.jar** in my project. When I define the dependency for both of them, Maven only picks one, since only the version is different. But I want both of them to be included. 
This is how I have defined them:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
  <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
  <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1-core</version>
</dependency>
```

Please help me regarding the same.

Comment: Did you find a solution for the first question (j2ee.jar in websphere)?

Comment: Not Yet... :( I used a different approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `j2ee.jar`, you have two options.  One is to install the jar to your local repository using `mvn install:install-file`.  The other is to specify it as a [system](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#System_Dependencies) dependency.

As for `castor-core`, you can add the `classifier` tag

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.castor</groupId>
  <artifactId>castor</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
  <classifier>core</classifier>
</dependency>
```